# Java Collections Binary Search : The method binarySearch in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, collections, iterator, comparator

I am trying to design a ride sharing system. Here is my base object

```
package rider;

import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Uber{

    String driver;
    TreeMap<Float,String> destination;

    public Uber(String d)
    {
        driver=d;
        destination = new TreeMap<Float,String>();
    }

    private void addTimeDest(float tm, String dest)
    {
        destination.put(tm, dest);
    }

    float getTsum() {

        float tsum=0;

        for (float f : this.destination.keySet())
            tsum+=f;
        return tsum;
    }

}
```

So, each object has a driver and an associated time<->destination map for that driver. Ultimately, i want to sort a list of such objects by the time field i.e. the key of the treemap.

and here is the iterator class i created for the above

```
package rider;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class UberIterator implements Iterator<Uber> {

    int currIndex=0;
    ArrayList<Uber> uList;
    Comparator<Uber> timeComparator = new Comparator<Uber>(){
          public int compare(Uber u1, Uber u2) {
              return (int) (u1.getTsum()-u2.getTsum());
        }
          };
    public UberIterator(ArrayList<Uber> nList)
    {
        uList=nList;
        Collections.sort(uList,timeComparator);
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {

        return currIndex<uList.size();
    }

    public Uber next() {
        return uList.get(currIndex++);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        uList.remove(currIndex--);
    }

    public void remove(String d) {

        int rindex=-1;
        for(int u=0 ; u<currIndex; u++)
        {
            if(uList.get(u).driver.equals(d))
            {
                rindex=u;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(rindex<0)
            System.out.println("Driver not found.");
        else
        {
            uList.remove(rindex);
            currIndex--;
        }
    }

    public void remove(float tm) {

        int rindex=Collections.binarySearch(uList, tm, timeComparator);

        if(rindex<0)
        {
            System.out.println("Exact time not found. Closest will be removed.");

        }
        else
        {
            uList.remove(rindex);
            currIndex--;
        }
    }

}
```

basically, with the comparator

```
Comparator<Uber> timeComparator = new Comparator<Uber>(){
          public int compare(Uber u1, Uber u2) {
              return (int) (u1.getTsum()-u2.getTsum());
        }
          };
```

i am trying to sort by the key of the internal treemap. but i get this error

```
The method binarySearch(List<? extends T>, T, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Uber>, float, Comparator<Uber>)
```

at

```
int rindex=Collections.binarySearch(uList, tm, timeComparator);
```

how should i correct my implementation?

**Follow Up**

is there a way to override `Collections.binarySearch` ? what if `Uber` implements `Comparable` and there i define the compare method as above? Shouldn't that automatically search with the `time` dimension? Otherwise what is the benefit of defining custom comparators for sorting? The sole reason i want to sort the list in a certain way is to be able to search it efficiently later on.

```
package rider;

import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Uber implements Comparable<Uber> {

    String driver;
    TreeMap<Float,String> destination;

    public Uber(String d)
    {
        driver=d;
        destination = new TreeMap<Float,String>();
    }

    private void addTimeDest(float tm, String dest)
    {
        destination.put(tm, dest);
    }

    public int compareTo(Uber u) {

        return (int) (this.getTsum()-u.getTsum());
    }

    float getTsum() {

        float tsum=0;

        for (float f : this.destination.keySet())
            tsum+=f;
        return tsum;
    }

}
```

Comment: It says it right there. Your middle argument must be a T type, which in this case is an Uber type. Pass it an Uber object instead of a float.

Comment: The second argument must be an Uber object, not a float. Read the documentation or the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> int rindex=Collections.binarySearch(uList, tm, timeComparator);

You cannot search for a `float` in a `List<Uber>`.

Your alternatives...frankly aren't that great.  You could create a fake `Uber` containing your `tm` value and pass that to `Collections.binarySearch`.  You could use a library like Guava, call `Lists.transform(ubers, getTmFunction)` to create a view, and pass that to `Collections.binarySearch`.  You could reimplement binary search yourself.

Comment: @AbtPst, in reaction to your second question: no, there isn't a way to do that.  `Collections.binarySearch` takes a value of the _same type_ as the list elements.  That doesn't make it useless -- most of the time that's what you have.  You just have one of the weird cases where that's not what you have.